# Backbone.js using non-restful actions on a restful model

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, backbone.js

I have a regular restful model that I do get, create, delete and update. On top of that, I'd like to call special actions on that model, like change_password.

The regular RESTful routes are traditional Rails 3 routes:

```
fetch   => GET    /api/models/:id
save    => PUT    /api/models/:id
create  => POST   /api/models
destroy => DELETE /api/models/:id
```

But, on top of those, I have special operations:

```
changePassword => GET /api/models/:id/change_password
activate       => GET /api/models/:id/activate
```

And so on.

What do I need to setup on the model, so it recognizes those new actions, and how to wrap the calls into model methods?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

It's fairly simple to add new methods to a Model - just specify the new methods in `.extend()`. You have to code some of this yourself, but you can take advantage of existing machinery like `Backbone.sync` (mostly just a wrapper around `$.ajax()`) and the Model's existing `url` property:

```
var MyModel = Backbone.Model.extend({

    activate: function(opts) {
        var model = this,
            url = model.url() + '/activate',
            // note that these are just $.ajax() options
            options = {
                url: url,
                type: 'POST' // see my note below
            };

        // add any additional options, e.g. a "success" callback or data
        _.extend(options, opts);

        return (this.sync || Backbone.sync).call(this, null, this, options);
    },

    // etc

});
```

Just as a comment, from a REST perspective, your `changePassword` and `activate` operations should *not* be GET methods - all GET methods should be idempotent. This is not just RESTifarianism, it's a Good Idea - you could end up caching these URLs (so nothing happens) or hitting them multiple times by accident (usually requiring user confirmation with a POST request). Make these POST calls if you can.

Comment: Thank you for the remark about GET vs. POST, I will change them for sure.

Comment: The 'POST' parameter seems not to have effect. The 'CLICK' verb seems to be used instead (Chrome).

Comment: Not sure what you mean here - there's no `CLICK` verb in HTTP, so ?

Answer (score 8):

I would advise that if possible add a Password model/controller where you can call **save** on to change the password. This follows the REST standards and is built in functionality of Backbone.js

If that's not an option, the following is a CoffeeScript example, add this to your model:

```
activate: ->
  unless user.get('active')
    (@sync || Backbone.sync).call @, 'activate', @,
      url: "#{@url()}/users/#{message.get('id')}/activate"
      data: {}
      complete: =>
        user.set(active: true)
        @set(active: true)
```

Comment: why does not work: `success: => console.log 'success'` (instead of complete)   ?